# XQuery and XPath - testing for child/attribute based on current attribute

Tags: xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have numerous xml files structured

```
<seg type="dep_event" xml:id="MS609-0000-01">
  <date type="event_date" when="1245"/>
</seg>
```

Where `<date type="event_date" when="1245">` is optional.

Now in Xpath/Xquery 3.1, I need test  for the existence of `date@when`, based on the **current context node** `seg/@xml:id`.

Imagine this situation in Xquery 3.1:

```
let $doc := doc(somedocument.xml)

for $xmlidattr in $doc//tei:seg[@type="dep_event"]/@xml:id
```

Now, I need to test `date/@when` using `$xmlidattr`

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: restructured question to be more clear about the idea of `context node` in XQuery

Comment: It turns out @choroba 's lead on `parent`was the right path, just needed adjusting for XQuery. The test would be `$xmlidattr/parent::tei:seg//tei:date[@type="event_date"]/@when`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent of the `id` is the `seg`, its child is the `date`:

```
../date[@type="event_date"][@when="1245"]
```

That was the answer to the original question. The question has changed and the new answer is

```
$xmlidattr/../date[@type="event_date"][@when="1245"]
```

However, I would normally start from the containing element rather than from the attribute:

```
for $seg in $doc//tei:seg[@type="dep_event"],
    $xmlidattr in $seg/@xml:id
return f($seg/date[@type="event_date"][@when="1245"])
```

Comment: The answer looks correct to me, and your comment looks wrong.

Comment: The comment I was commenting on disappeared while I was commenting on it...

Comment: @MichaelKay  When testing the answer here I realized that a generic XPATH answer might not work and so I was wrong in my response. I updated my question to provide the XPATH problem in XQuery context. Thanks.

Comment: @choroba your answer is generally correct. In testing it I realized I should have been more specific about the XQuery context. I have updated the question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Sorry for that.